# 74hc165 inverting pins 15 and 2, does it work?

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, shift-register

I have a board that uses **74hc165** shift registers, when taking a look at schematic it appears that **pins 2 (clk)** and **pin 15 (clk enable)** are **inverted**, my first impression was that this is a mistake, but when verifying the board it turns out that **this is not a mistake**, so I had to take a look at the datasheet of the 74hc165, and I found out that those pins can be inverted, so I decided to do a simulation using Proteus unfortunately it didn't work, and I don't have this IC (74hc165) with me to do a hardware test so...Do you have guys any idea about this?? I'm so confused..

Comment: Why do you need to test a documented functionality? You don't believe the datasheet?

Comment: Please read the question before answering, I said that I took a look at the datasheet and those pins can be inverted, and the board is working perfectly.

Comment: Reading the question: The schematic says - it is inverted. Verification on the board says - it is inverted. Datasheet says - it is inverted (or can be inverted). So? No evidence they are *not* inverted. What exactly are you trying to test here?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: For some reason, the inputs are labeled as one being active high and one active low, but both inputs are in fact interchangeable inputs to an OR gate.  The only reason the enable is called active-low is that when it's high the output of the OR gate will stay high and thus won't propagate any clock pulses, but that only makes sense if clock is regarded as being active low but triggers on the trailing edge.

Answer (score 2):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, you are confusing people with the word "inverted" where you meant "swapped".

From the datasheet, pin 2 and pin 15 feed the same OR gate that then feed the edge-trigger clock of the internal registers. So they are functionally equivalent. And it is confirmed in the "function table" and they even share the same setup and hold time from "Dynamic characteristics". The specific datasheet I am looking at is from NXP.

Answer (score 1):

This all just a semantic and political problem in that if the clock control input is called "CLOCK ENABLE" - like on the NXP data sheet - it must be low when clock goes high in order to allow the high-going edges of the clock to propagate through the OR and into the shift register body.

If it's called "CLOCK INHIBIT" - like on the TI data sheet - then, when it's high,   clocks can't propagate through the OR and into the shift register body.

So, since the controlling gate is a 2 input OR, if either input is low the output will follow the other input, but if either input is a high the output will be forced high for that input's high lifetime.

Comment: Personally, I dislike both terms to describe the function, since to my mind edges on something that calls itself a clock-enable or clock-inhibit function should not be registered as clock events.  Better would be to use clk1 and /clk2, and specify that either pin may clock the device when the other is active.

Comment: @supercat; You seem to have missed the point, which was that the gating events aren't clock events but which, rather, allow clock events to happen.

Comment: I checked the data sheet and its terminology is even more confusing than I remembered.

Comment: @supercat: That's probably not the  data sheet's fault ;)

Comment: It's the fault of whoever wrote the first specification for the part.  Calling the inputs "clk1" and "clk2" and specifying that the part will respond to a rising edge either while the other is low would have been clearer.  Labeling one input as active high and the other as active low *when both are functionally identical* is just plain weird, especially since there are other parts that label pins similarly but do in fact give them different functions.

Comment: Just more semantics, and to which data sheet are you referring?  Calling the inputs "clk1" and "clk2" implies dual clocks where, generally, such is not the case and, in this case, since one of the inputs is clearly defined as enabling/inhibiting the other , there's only one clock and its switch.

Comment: It would imply that there are two inputs which may be used as clocks that react to the same edge.  Check http://nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT165.pdf and you'll notice that it has two interchangeable inputs that respond to the same clock edges; I don't think the given names imply that *at all*.  What names would you like better?

Comment: @supercat: I have no preference; it depends on the circuit.

Comment: The internal circuit is an OR gate which takes the two inputs and feeds them to a rising-edge detect.  The external circuit could of course be just about anything.

Comment: @supercat: Since the circuitry internal to the '165 is carved in stone, the circuit to which I was referring **was** the external circuit and, for example, if I wanted to inhibit the clock when the serial output went high, I'd pass its high true output, which I'd call "CLK INH" to either pin 2 or pin 15 (whatever was more convenient for the PC layout) and route the clock to the other pin.

Comment: For an external-signal label, the name should be dependent upon usage, though pins strapped high or low generally don't need external net names.  Datasheet labels, however, should relate to what signals do in a device.  The idea that releasing "clock enable" when clock is in its "inactive" state should trigger a clocking event is IMHO bizarre.  The only way the behavior of "/clock enable" would make sense would be if clock were active low, but latching and output were deferred until the trailing edge (so a release of /enable would be seen as a trailing clock edge).

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a flaw in your logic notation, but since the system is screaming about taking this to chat, I'm game. Wanna play?

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible simple answer. From the datasheet it is visible that we have a NOT CE  while the CP is not inverted. For the designer of the system it might have been more conveniënt to use the inverted channel. So swapping the pins was more handy and might have saved one or more inverters

Comment: Neither channel is actually inverted, though.  The device will respond to a rising edge on CP when /CE is low, or to a rising edge on /CE when CP is low.

Answer (score 0):

Since TTL had lower impedance active LOW , LOW is used for **PE** &  **CE**, this "negative" logic was carried forward from 74LSxxx to 74HCxxx for CMOS compatibility on TTL replacements.

- you may use CP=1 (pin2) and negative edge of CE (pin 15)
- or CE= 0 (pin 15) and use the positive edge of CP (pin 2), (clk. pulse)

  - since these are OR'd clock inputs as shown in the Truth table.

Side notes

CMOS is more symmetrical in low driver impedance for Hi or Low.
The 74HCxxx has mid level logic thresholds like most CMOS, while the 74HCTxxx family has true TTL thresholds of 1.4V with margins define by 0.8 & 2.0V or 1.4V +/- 0.6V as the "undefined zone" where noise margin is added to ensure reliable logic levels with noise immunity at temperature extremes.

Comment: Some parts use "Clock & !ClockEnable" as a clock, but this one uses "Clock | ClockEnable" meaning that a rising edge on either while the other is low will be registered as an active event.  I have no idea why that was considered a useful design.  The former avoids allows a device to be used for applications requiring clocking on rising or falling edges by feeding one input and strapping the other, but the redundant clock seems pretty useless.

Comment: From what I recall EVERY  family of xx'165's are logically the same so your equiv cct. must have an inverter on CE! in front of the Clock OR gate, this gives the flexibility of using either clock edge to handle latency in synchronous registers from one type to another in case of skew.

Comment: Check the data sheet, e.g. http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT165.pdf and you'll notice that it responds to rising edges on /CE while CP is low, or rising edges on CP while /CE is low.  Despite the labels, the two inputs are equivalent, and there is no meaningful sense in which one is inverted and the other one not.

Answer (score 0):

On some devices which include a rising-edge clock pin and an active-low clock-enable pin, the enable pin is only effective on a rising clock edge; the behavior of the two pins is somewhat like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNgpWF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If enable is low (active) when clock is low, then AND1, OR1, and AND2 will switch on.  If clock goes high while the enable is still low, AND1 will go low but OR1 and AND1 will keep each other high, and AND3 will go high so the clock pulse will percolate through to the output.

If enable is high (inactive), AND1, AND2, and AND3 will all be forced low, as will OR1 (which is fed by AND1 and AND2).  If the clock is high when enable goes low, all of the gates will remain off until both clock and enable are low simultaneously.

The inputs on the 74HC165 don't work that way, though it's possible some simulators might erroneously believe that they do.  The actual behavior is simply:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP6Bcr.png)</sup>

The device may be clocked either be holding clock enable low while clock goes high, holding the clock low while clock enable goes high, or by simultaneously switching both clock and clock enable from low to high.  While such versatility might be useful in some cases, it's not nearly as useful as would be many other possible arrangements.